# TiKz Kiviat Chart - Label numbering from 0.0 to 1.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-kiviat

I'm trying to create a Kiviat diagram. The axis must have label values from 0.0 to 1.0.  I used `\pgfmathresult/10` but I only got integer numbers.

Below I present the code that I'm using. Can anybody help me to get labels values from 0.0 to 1.0

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newcommand\ColorBox[1]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{2ex}{2ex}}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tkz@KiviatGrad}{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathresult/10}
         {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}
         {\ERRORpatchfailed}
\makeatother 
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=.15cm, scale=0.5]
 \tkzKiviatDiagram[radial  style/.style ={-}, lattice style/.style ={black!30}]% 
{$Q_u$, $Q_c$, $Q_d$, $Q_{da}$, $Q_m$, $Q_p$, $Q_t$}
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=red!20,
                mark=ball,
                ball color=red!20,
                mark size=4pt,
                fill=red!20](8,7.5,10,10,9,9,7.5)
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue!20,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,
                mark color=blue!20,
                fill=blue!20,
                opacity=.5](8.6,9,10,10,8,5,5)


  \tkzKiviatGrad[suffix=,unity=1](0)


\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{figure}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change you made doesn't work because `\tkz@KiviatGrad` uses `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` in the next step. You'll need to change that to `\pgfmathsetmacro`. Because that gave me some precision issues (e.g. `0.20001` instead of `0.2`) I used `\pgfmathprintnumber` to format the number afterwards. And because there isn't much space, I moved the labels to the second axis, and reduced the font size to `\tiny`. Note  I set `unity=0.1` instead of dividing by 10 in `\tkz@KiviatGrad`.

See comments in code.

[image: Output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat}
\makeatletter
\def\tkz@KiviatGrad[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/kiviatgrad/.cd,
graduation distance= 0 pt,
prefix ={},
suffix={},
unity=1
 }
 \pgfqkeys{/kiviatgrad}{#1}% 
\let\tikz@label@distance@tmp\tikz@label@distance
\global\let\tikz@label@distance\tkz@kiv@grad
 \foreach \nv in {1,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{
 \pgfmathparse{\tkz@kiv@unity*\nv} 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult} % change from \pgfmathtruncatemacro
 \protected@edef\tkz@kiv@gd{\tkz@kiv@prefix\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed]{\result}\tkz@kiv@suffix} % used \pgfmathprintnumber instead of "$\result$"
    \path[/kiviatgrad/.cd,#1] (0:0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2:\nv*\tkz@kiv@gap) 
       node[label=(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2)-90:\tiny\tkz@kiv@gd] {}; % added \tiny
      }
 \let\tikz@label@distance\tikz@label@distance@tmp  
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=.15cm,scale=0.5]
 \tkzKiviatDiagram[radial  style/.style ={-}, lattice style/.style ={black!30}]% 
{$Q_u$, $Q_c$, $Q_d$, $Q_{da}$, $Q_m$, $Q_p$, $Q_t$}

\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=0.1](1) % set unity as 0.1
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```